# Function does not return correct resource

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
function query_dp($sql) {
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', $bd_id, $bd_pass);
    mysql_select_db("$bd");

    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    return mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_close($link);
}
```

In the main program, when I try to do:

```
echo mysql_num_rows(query_db($sql));
```

I get as return

```
1
```

When I do not encapsulate that code in a function and use it directly to the main program, I get the number of rows fetched.

The function is not returning a Resource but an... integer? WTF?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can't close the link after the return. you don't want to close the link until you are done reading from it.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but you are calling `query_db()` but your function is called `query_dp()`

Comment: BTW your return before your mysql_close() ends the function call. The mysql_close() is not even being called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables `$bd_id`, `$bd_pass` and `$bd` are not visible inside the function since they are probably declared in the global [scope](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and not the local scope of that function.

You would either make the global variables accessible by using the [`global` keyword](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global), by using the [`$GLOBALS` variable](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php), or by [passing them to the function](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

Answer (score 1):

your call to mysql_close means that you no longer have a link to the mysql resource that you need in mysql_num_rows

Comment: You can't close a connection after a return ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in "or" operator. Your function returns result of "mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())" expression, which is 1 or 0. I suggest you to use something like this:

```
$query_result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$query_result) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
return $query_result;
```

Also last line of this function "mysql_close($link)" is never called.

Comment: Wrong, the 'OR DIE' PHP trick has been valid since v.3.0. Search SO, there is a relevant question. Though I have to admit it is a very bab habit.

Comment: Please try to run code from http://pastebin.com/m4301f239. You'll see `bool(true)`, but not the `string(6) "string"`

Comment: This how the OR operator works. In the case of function thing() it is evaluated as TRUE (or actually as NOT FALSE, see http://www.php.net/manual/ro/language.types.boolean.php), therefore the DIE part is never executed.

This is the same with mysql_connect function. If the connection fails the shortcircuit OR operator chooses the second part (DIE).

Comment: That's exactly why `return mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` will never return sql statement result

Comment: In case it's not clear, @IvanNevostruev is correct.  Other languages (e.g., Javascript and Python) do behave as described in the comments; e.g., `5 || 3` yields `5`, but in PHP, `5 || 3` yields `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but you shouldn't use the original mysql interface. it is clunky and procedural. Take a look at the [mysqli interface](https://www.php.net/mysqli). Don't try to wrap the old functions if you have a language supported standard that already does this :D

You above code just becomes

```
$m = new MysqlI(...);
$rc = $m->query(...);
echo $rc->num_rows();
```