# PHP mysql_query, integer returned instead of resource

Tags: php, mysql

Before anyone jumps on me, I have found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539978/function-does-not-return-correct-resource), but unfortunately their answer does not seem to apply to my problem.

I have created a function called `sqlReturn()` in order to more easily produce an error (with standard output) should a query go wrong.  The code is below:

```
function sqlResult($query)
{
    return mysql_query($query) 
    or die("SQL Query: " . $query . "<br />SQL Error: " . mysql_error());
}
```

As you can see, it just outputs an error in the way I like, and it saves me a bit of effort in coding along the way.  However, while this has been working in most cases (eg. situations where I use SELECT or INSERT), it is throwing the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, 
              boolean given in /var/www/login/login_submit.php on line 42
```

It is returning 1 instead of a resource.  If, instead of calling that function (which is in a separate php file), I simply use the line of code in the same file without a return statement
(ie. `$sqlResult = mysql_query($sqlQuery) or ...` etc.), it returns a resource as normal.

In case it's relevant, my SQL query is also below:

```
$sqlQuery = 
  "SELECT userID, username, password, access_level
   FROM users
   WHERE username = '{$username}'
   AND (password = '{$password_sha1}' OR password = '{$password_sha256}')";
```

Any input on this would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Paragon

Comment: Please post code up to `mysql_fetch_array()` ...

Comment: @frankie: that's a standard PHP function...

Comment: @Marc B I suspect Paragon is feeding the function with a "boolean" :)

Comment: It's a string.  I'm entering the query $sqlQuery as posted above.

Comment: @Paragon, feeding mysql_fetch_array() with $sqlQuery wont work. You have to feed it with the result of `mysql_query`

Comment: My mistake in the comment.  That code is correct.  Please, this is not the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sneaky suspicion that binding rules are kicking in here. PHP may be seeing your function as

```
return (mysql_query(...)) or die(...);
```

and return before ever seeing the die(). Try rewriting like this

```
function sqlQuery(...) {
    $result = mysql_query(...);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error(...));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

so there's no chance of any mis-parsing.

Comment: Hey,I was quite skeptical of your response, since my query was fine (ie. I didn't need the 'die').  But it works!

Can you please explain to me exactly what is going on here, or link me to a resource that would do so?  Thanks!

Comment: `return` has a higher precedence than `or`. So the query call goes out, returns, and its result gets sucked up by return, which transfers execution back to whatever call the function originally, without ever reaching the `or` clause. It's kinda like sending your dog out to fetch your slippers and pipe, but shooting it after getting the slippers. The order to get the pipe is still there, but can't ever happen because the dog's dead.

Comment: @Marc_B LOL is that Schrodingers dog that you shot? 'cause than it's still in with a chance,

Comment: Great, thanks very much!  PS: Johan, I can't say I understand your sentence at all.